# Get loop counter/index using for…of syntax in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, for-loop, foreach, counter

I understand that the basic `for...of` syntax in JavaScript looks like this:

```js
for (let obj of myArray) {
  // ...
}
```

But how do I get the loop counter/index when iterating with this syntax?

(With the same question applying to `for...in` notation for iterating over object property names)

I know I can use an explicit loop counter like:

```js
for (let i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
  const obj = myArray[i];
  console.log(i);
}
```

Or manually track the index outside of the loop:

```js
let i = 0;
for (let obj of myArray) {
  console.log(i);
  i++;
}
```

But I would rather use the simpler `for...of` loop, I think they look better and make more sense.

As an example of a language that lets you do this, in Python it's as easy as:

```py
for i, obj in enumerate(my_array):
    print(i)
```

Comment: Don't use for...in for arrays. And anyways, it iterates over the property names, not the values of the properties.

Comment: It's an array, not an object, right?  So, `alert(obj)`?

Answer (score 1109, accepted):

`for…in` iterates over property names, not values, and does so [in an unspecified order](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/index.html#sec-ordinary-object-internal-methods-and-internal-slots-enumerate) (yes, even after ES6). You shouldn’t use it to iterate over arrays. For them, there’s ES5’s `forEach` method that passes both the value and the index to the function you give it:

```
var myArray = [123, 15, 187, 32];

myArray.forEach(function (value, i) {
    console.log('%d: %s', i, value);
});

// Outputs:
// 0: 123
// 1: 15
// 2: 187
// 3: 32
```

Or ES6’s [`Array.prototype.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/entries), which now has support across current browser versions:

```
for (const [i, value] of myArray.entries()) {
    console.log('%d: %s', i, value);
}
```

For iterables in general (where you would use a `for…of` loop rather than a `for…in`), there’s nothing built-in, however:

```
function* enumerate(iterable) {
    let i = 0;

    for (const x of iterable) {
        yield [i, x];
        i++;
    }
}

for (const [i, obj] of enumerate(myArray)) {
    console.log(i, obj);
}
```

If you actually did mean `for…in` – enumerating properties – you would need an additional counter. `Object.keys(obj).forEach` could work, but it only includes *own* properties; `for…in` includes enumerable properties anywhere on the prototype chain.

Comment: Actually, obj will be the array index, but there is no guarantee that it is in order and that it won't include other property names.

Comment: don't you need to do var i = 0, because lets are unchanging?

Comment: @quantumpotato: `let`s are `var`s with block scope. `const`s are unchanging.

Comment: I did not know this was possible: `myArray.forEach(function (value, *i*)` (emphasis mine). This is perfect. I knew there had to be a better way than that `myArray.indexOf(value)` garbage I've been doing. +1.

Comment: In the example above, 'i' which should be the index returns undefined, please help.

Comment: @Ade In which example?

Comment: I have sorted my self now. (The mistake I'd made was following your solution whilst still using the ECMA arrow and without the keyword, "function". Thanks Ry.

Comment: stupid question but what does %d and %s actually stand for, or could they be any letter I want them to be?

Comment: @klewis: `%d` formats an integer and `%s` formats a string. They’re inspired by [printf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string). A spec is in progress at https://console.spec.whatwg.org/#formatter.

Comment: Note the other answer below in reference to arrow functions... But the above does work too.

Comment: The downside of `forEach` is that `await` inside is scoped to the function parameter, not the outer scope. So if you want to await inside the loop, you probably want to use `.entries()`.

Comment: Which one is faster in Node 18?

Comment: @Antoine: It’s usually close enough not to matter in modern V8; I essentially always use `for of`. You can benchmark your own use case to get concrete numbers.

Comment: Note: you should take special precautions if you're using an async callback with something like foreach since it would run the loops in parallel if you were hoping to run in serial.

Comment: From MDN: "The traversal order, as of modern ECMAScript specification, is well-defined and consistent across implementations. Within each component of the prototype chain, all non-negative integer keys (those that can be array indices) will be traversed first in ascending order by value, then other string keys in ascending chronological order of property creation." https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#description

Answer (score 463):

In ES6, it is good to use a `for... of` loop.
You can get index in `for... of` like this

```
for (let [index, val] of array.entries()) {
  // your code goes here    
}
```

Note that `Array.entries()` returns [an iterator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/entries), which is what allows it to work in the for-of loop; don't confuse this with [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries), which returns an *array* of key-value pairs.

Comment: I think this solution is better than the forEach one... It uses the nomral for...of loop syntax, and you don't have to use a separate function. In other words, it's syntactically better. The OP seems to have wanted this.

Comment: `entries()` is returning an empty object: `{}`. Any idea why that would be? My `array` is an Array of Objects.

Comment: @JoshuaPinter try `Object.entries(array)` instead of `array.entries()`

Comment: It's supposed to do that, Joshua - the object is an iterator, an object with a `next()` method that will return subsequent entries in the array each time it is called. There's no (visible) data in it; you get the data in the underlying object by calling `next()`, which for-of does behind the scenes. cc @tonyg

Comment: woah, I take it back. I was using a repl and `array.entries()` always returns `{}` but if you actually use the code above, using `for ... of array.entries()` it works just fine. Sorry about that.

Comment: Also this allows `await` to work in sequence, whereas `forEach` does not.

Comment: Be aware this only works for `Array`. `for...of` works on any `Iterable`. You might have to convert to `Array` with `for (const [index, value] of [...array].entries())`. Iterables include `HTMLCollection` `NodeList`, and other DOM classes.

Comment: nicely done! ...

Comment: Why use `let` instead of `const`?

Comment: I agree with @Ben. The values don't change in scope so should be `const`, not `let`.

Answer (score 54):

How about this

```
let numbers = [1,2,3,4,5]
numbers.forEach((number, index) => console.log(`${index}:${number}`))
```

Where `array.forEach` this method has an `index` parameter which is the index of the current element being processed in the array.

Comment: The chosen answer was posted 6 years before this one and has the same thing already in it...

Comment: Foreach is not good for optimization, since `break` is not available.

Comment: @smartworld-dm I do agree with this but there is the simple return statement.

Answer (score 21):

Solution for small array collections:

```
for (var obj in arr) {
    var i = Object.keys(arr).indexOf(obj);
}
```

**arr** - ARRAY,
 **obj** - KEY of current element,
 **i** - COUNTER/INDEX

**Notice:** Method *keys()* is not available for IE version <9, you should use *Polyfill* code.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

Comment: I'd suggest: use a counter instead, increment it in loop.

Comment: Adding on to mayankcpdixit, use a counter instead because indexOf could have a negative performance impact.

Comment: The larger the object, the slower this will get. This does not scale.

Comment: This is kind of pointlessly slow and complicated because `var i = 0;` and `i++;` is shorter and more efficient. Plus it doesn't work for enumerable properties that aren't own properties.

Comment: @mayankcpdixit Incrementing a counter won't work in for..of loops that modify the array during iteration.

Comment: @Ryan `var i = 0;` and `i++;` won't work in loops that modify the array during iteration. @rushUp's answer is superb, because the index will be the original index of each item before iteration, regardless of the array being modified during iteration.

Comment: @trusktr: Why are you replying to a comment about this answer, which iterates over an array in ϴ(n²) time?

Comment: @trusktr yes! but `for...of` is still relatively new. If you're using `for...in`, _counter_ would be a good coice.

Comment: @Ryan If modifying the collection during iteration isn't required, then yeah, a regular for loop is a good way to make it faster. :}

Comment: @trusktr: And if it is required… you should still not use this. Just alter the counter when you alter the collection. If it doesn’t have to be in-place, do a nice functional transformation instead.

Comment: @Ryan That makes code harder to read. I would say it depends on the use case. If you are using it for something that the end user will not perceive performance-wise, then use it. For 60fps graphics? Maybe not.

Comment: @trusktr: Which option to pick depends on the use case. Whether to pick *this* option does not. There is no reason to get a new `Object.keys` and call `indexOf` on it for each item, ever. It takes time proportional to n² instead of n and is even less readable than a regular explicit loop.

Comment: This has horrible performance characteristics, and should not be suggested ever.

Comment: And it won't work it some value are duplicated in the array

Comment: @JaysonMinard To be fair, the author did specify "small arrays". Performance is usually not a concern there.

Comment: why learn the non performant way ever when the better options are just as easy?  this is how people learn bad habits and don't know they are bad habits.

Comment: How on Earth did anybody upvote this?

Answer (score 17):

For-in-loops iterate over properties of an Object. Don't use them for Arrays, even if they sometimes work.

Object properties then have no index, they are all equal and not required to be run through in a determined order. If you want to count properties, you will have to set up the extra counter (as you did in your first example).

loop over an Array:

```
var a = [];
for (var i=0; i<a.length; i++) {
    i // is the index
    a[i] // is the item
}
```

loop over an Object:

```
var o = {};
for (var prop in o) {
    prop // is the property name
    o[prop] // is the property value - the item
}
```

Comment: Never do `(var i=0; i<a.length; i++)` as is wasted resources. Use `(var i=0, var len = a.length; i<len; i++)`

Comment: @FelixSanz: Waste resources? No way. That is a premature micro-optimisation that is hardly ever necessary, and `var i=0; i<a.length; i++)` is the standard loop pattern that is optimised by every decent javascript engine anyway.

Comment: best practices are best practices!

Comment: @FelixSanz: Yes, and `var i=0; i<a.length; i++` is the best practise.

Comment: [KISS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle). If you write loops where you really need this you either are doing something wrong, or you have a better argument for its necessity than "best practise". Yes, it is a standard practise, but not for generic performance optimisation, but only for micro-optimisation.

Comment: KISS is just a principle. You are not proving it applies here, i did. so i won't reply anymore. do whatever you want.

Comment: KISS applies everywhere. [Premature optimisation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Premature_optimisation) is an anti-practise.

Answer (score 11):

As others have said, you shouldn't be using for..in to iterate over an array.

```
for ( var i = 0, len = myArray.length; i < len; i++ ) { ... }
```

If you want cleaner syntax, you could use forEach:

```
myArray.forEach( function ( val, i ) { ... } );
```

If you want to use this method, make sure that you include the ES5 shim to add support for older browsers.

Answer (score 7):

Answer Given by rushUp Is correct but this will be more convenient

```
for (let [index, val] of array.entries() || []) {
   // your code goes here    
}
```

Comment: `|| []` is unnecessary and will never be used; `array.entries()` is always truthy.

Comment: [index, val] never works for me, it says "undefined"

Comment: can you share your array ?

Comment: Why repeat an existing answer? Downvoted.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a function `eachWithIndex` that works with anything iterable.

You could also write a similar function `eachWithKey` that works with objets using `for...in`.

```
// example generator (returns an iterator that can only be iterated once)
function* eachFromTo(start, end) { for (let i = start; i <= end; i++) yield i }

// convers an iterable to an array (potential infinite loop)
function eachToArray(iterable) {
    const result = []
    for (const val of iterable) result.push(val)
    return result
}

// yields every value and index of an iterable (array, generator, ...)
function* eachWithIndex(iterable) {
    const shared = new Array(2)
    shared[1] = 0
    for (shared[0] of iterable) {
        yield shared
        shared[1]++
    }
}

console.log('iterate values and indexes from a generator')
for (const [val, i] of eachWithIndex(eachFromTo(10, 13))) console.log(val, i)

console.log('create an array')
const anArray = eachToArray(eachFromTo(10, 13))
console.log(anArray)

console.log('iterate values and indexes from an array')
for (const [val, i] of eachWithIndex(anArray)) console.log(val, i)
```

The good thing with generators is that they are lazy and can take another generator's result as an argument.

Answer (score 2):

That's my version of a composite iterator that yields an index and any passed generator function's value with an example of (slow) prime search:

```js
const eachWithIndex = (iterable) => {
  return {
    *[Symbol.iterator]() {
      let i = 0
      for(let val of iterable) {
        i++
          yield [i, val]
      }
    }
  }

}

const isPrime = (n) => {
  for (i = 2; i < Math.floor(Math.sqrt(n) + 1); i++) {
    if (n % i == 0) {
      return false
    }
  }
  return true
}

let primes = {
  *[Symbol.iterator]() {
    let candidate = 2
    while (true) {
      if (isPrime(candidate)) yield candidate
        candidate++
    }
  }
}

for (const [i, prime] of eachWithIndex(primes)) {
  console.log(i, prime)
  if (i === 100) break
}
```

Comment: Why do you have a function `eachWithIndex[Symbol.iterator]` instead of just a function `eachWithIndex`? `eachWithIndex` doesn’t satisfy the iterable interface, which is the whole point of `Symbol.iterator`.

Comment: @Ry- Good catch, changed `eachWithIndex` to accept iterable and return a closured composite iterable.

Answer (score 2):

On top of the very good answers everyone posted I want to add that the most performant solution is the ES6 `entries`. It seems contraintuitive for many devs here, so I created [this perf benchamrk](https://jsperf.com/enumerate/1).

[image]

It's ~6 times faster. Mainly because doesn't need to: a) access the array more than once and, b) cast the index.

Comment: I've got to say you are not comparing apple to apple in the above test case. In classic, extra const v is defined plus the unnecessary type conversion Number(i) all led to its overhead. By removing those bits, my result shows the contrary: classic is 4 times faster. Please check the updated version [here](https://jsperf.com/enumerate/5)

Comment: @Marshal  Your link is dead

Comment: @javadba, That's because [jsperf is down](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37695890/how-to-profile-javascript-now-that-jsperf-is-down). I'll create a new answer

Comment: Saying it’s the “most performant solution” based on a benchmark that only includes one other approach (that also happens to be wrong) is pretty misleading. How about comparing it against the top answers?

Answer (score 0):

One answer that seems to be missing is that in Python, the enumeration is a function. So: you could just do the same in JavaScript and then destructure during your `for...of` loop:

```js
// Stick this in any random utils.js that you can import from
function enumerate(arr) {
  return arr.map((element, i) => [i, element]);
}

const myArray = ['a','b','c','d','e'];

// And then loop over *that* instead of the plain array:
for (let [i, element] of enumerate(myArray)) {
  console.log(i, element);
}
```

But I'd probably go with a `map` instead, of course:

```
myArray.forEach((element, i) => {
  console.log(i, element);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

```
// this loop is used in advanced javascript
//For Example I have an array:
let array = [1,2,3,4,5];
1) for(let key in array){
      console.log(key);//this shows index of array {Result: 0,1,2,3,4}
      console.log(array[key]);//this show values of array {Result: 1,2,3,4,5}
   }
//Hopefully, You will quickly understand;
```

Answer (score -5):

To use for..of loop on array and retrieve index you can you use `array1.indexOf(element)` which will return the index value of an element in the loop. You can return both the index and the value using this method.

```js
array1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
for (element of array1) {
    console.log(array1.indexOf(element), element) // 0 a 1 b 2 c
}
```

As mentionned in comments, this will return false index when the array contains non uniques values. (considering arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a'], index of arr[3] will return 0 instead of 3) so this should be better suited for Sets than for Arrays.

Comment: Please explain your code a little as to what it does rather than adding snippets only. Plus it doesn't exactly answer the question. The question is rather about objects and taking an example of an array would perhaps be oversimplification. (From Review)

Comment: useful with iterable objects, thanks pal, my_list.indexOf(element), though lambda expressions forEach is very useful.

Comment: This is unnecessarily quadratic and will produce incorrect results when the array contains duplicates.