# "Edit A tag target attribute vs Add eventlistener" to open on new window

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I am working with a large site with several hundred pages. Now, I want to add a logic to edit the existing pages' anchor tags' target attribute. In my script, should I modify the existing target attribute and let the Browser handle the HTML? like

```
$(this).attr('target', '_blank');
```

or should I add an eventListener that prevents default execution and handles redirection through window object? like

```
$(this).click(function(event){
       event.preventDefault();
       event.stopPropagation();
       window.open($(this).href(), '_blank');
});
```

- which is the better to use?
- is one always better than the other in
  terms of performance?

Comment: The two snippets are doing a different job, and you use the one you need, performance in this context is meaningless.

Comment: @Teemu how are the two snippets doing different things? the motive of both the snippets is to open a new tab on an onclick event of an anchor tag.

Comment: The first snippet lets user open a new tab without JS interfering, in the second snippet you open the tab with JS, which makes it possible to interact with the opened tab, and even close it programmatically, which is not possible with the first snippet.

Comment: @Teemu that's my question. Look this from the user view. do not care about how the functionality is implemented. in user point of view, if you click the link it should go to the href url in new tab. my question is, which way it should be implement. is it better to implement it through js or just use js to edit the target attribute in HTML? which would give me a better performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you want to do is have all anchors open in a new tab, I'd go with:

```
$('a').attr('target', '_blank');
```

As it is faster.

Performance test here: https://jsfiddle.net/7q01foa2/2/

I setup the performance test, using a JSFiddle template(see this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37695890/how-to-profile-javascript-now-that-jsperf-is-down)), using benchmark.js

Hope that helped?