# How does for..of loop get values from Array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, for-of-loop

I have this piece of code,

```js
let array = ["cj1rdd9fc00013f69ccln57g0", "cj1rdda8x00023f69g9281ay8"];
for (let [key, value] of array) {
  console.log(key, value);
}
```

I expect, 0 cj1rdd9fc00013f69ccln57g0 and 1 cj1rdda8x00023f69g9281ay8 as the output. what am I missing here? How can I get the desired output?

Comment: What are you getting? Some errors or current results would help please.

Comment: @ChrisWatts OP expects `key` to be indexes and `value` to be element of array

Comment: Refer https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of

Comment: I found that adding array.entries() in the loop body makes it work fine.

Comment: @AkhileshBhushan, see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43534850/2545680) for in-depth explanation.

Comment: Don't put answers in the questions. Instead, accept the correct answer.

Comment: Read the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of), where `for...of` is described with perfect clarity.

Comment: @torazaburo, it's missing some in-depth details though, for example, two iterators I mentioned in [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43534850/2545680)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Let try to understand whats happening here:**

As per [MDN-Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of), `for..of` provides value of each iteration to the assignment.

So when you do `for(var v of array)`, `v` will hold value.

Now when you do `let [key, value]`, you are using something thats called as [Destructuring Assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment).

What it does is, for given list of variables, it will assign values at corresponding index value.

So, in `let [a,b] = [10, 20]`, `a=10` and `b=20`.

Coming back to your example,

```
let [key, value] of array,
```

is evaluated as `let [key, value] = "cj1rdd9fc00013f69ccln57g0"`, so `key` holds value at 0th index, a.k.a `c` and value holds `j`.

---

**How can I get the desired output**

You can use other looping mechanisms like `for`, `array.forEach` etc.

There are other mechanisms like `.map`, `.filter`, `.some`, `.every`, `.reduce` but they have their own usecase, and can be suggested based on the processing logic.

#### Array.forEach

```js
let array = ["cj1rdd9fc00013f69ccln57g0", "cj1rdda8x00023f69g9281ay8"];

array.forEach(function(value, index){
  console.log(index, value)
})
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation, well my use case was not that simple, as I had to use async and await in the loop.

Comment: I know that. Hence have mentioned other options. Read about them and choose based on your requirement. Also do check their browser compatibility.

Comment: I have edited my query with the answer and actual async function, thank you.

Comment: @Rajesh, you may find [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43534850/2545680) interesting

Answer (score 4):

**Here is a bit of under the hood explanation.**

`for..of` loop works on [iterables](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_iteration.html). On each iteration it calls `iterator.next().value` to get values. Standard `Array` implementation has **two kinds of iterators** - the one that returns only values and the other that returns `[key, value]` pairs. If you need to get the second type of iterator, use `array.entries()`.

```
let array = ["cj1rdd9fc00013f69ccln57g0", "cj1rdda8x00023f69g9281ay8"];
for (let [key, value] of array.entries()) {
  console.log(key, value);
}
```

Here is the demo of two types of iterators:

```
var arr = ['a','b'];
var valueIterator = arr[Symbol.iterator]();
valueIterator.next().value; // returns a
valueIterator.next().value; // returns b

var arr = ['a','b'];
var valueKeyIterator = arr.entries();
valueKeyIterator.next().value; // returns [0, a]
valueKeyIterator.next().value; // returns [1, b]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation :)

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of

The way `for of` works is each time it will grab just the value, not the index.

```
let array = ["cj1rdd9fc00013f69ccln57g0", "cj1rdda8x00023f69g9281ay8"];
for (let item of array) {
  console.log(item);
}
```

If you want to include the index, see this question:

[How do you get the loop counter/index using a for-in syntax in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10179815/how-do-you-get-the-loop-counter-index-using-a-for-in-syntax-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

This Code, Console.log Array

```js
 let array = ["cj1rdd9fc00013f69ccln57g0", "cj1rdda8x00023f69g9281ay8"];
 var i,j,tempstring;
    for (i=0,j=array.length; i<j; i++) {
        tempstring = array[i];
        console.log(tempstring);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a destructuring assignment . This will work for es6 Maps and not for Arrays . For arrays you can just use a for of loop .

Comment: I found that adding array.entries() in the loop body makes it work fine.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to get the value and index of an array in every iteration using some fancy iteration, try this.

```
let array = ["cj1rdd9fc00013f69ccln57g0", "cj1rdda8x00023f69g9281ay8"];
array.map((value, index) => {
    console.log(index, key);
});
```

Comment: `array.map` without return statement and assignment is just **bad** coding. You are wasting a feature. Use `.forEach` instead

Comment: I would respectfully disagree. Even in strong typed languages such as Java, you are not bound to use a value returned by a function.

Comment: I'm sorry if I was not clear enough. Every function has its own purpose. `Array.map` maps certain property or mutates value of every iteration. But if you are not returning value, it will return `undefined` manually. Then you are not assigning it to something, but `.map` will return an array created internally with undefined values. So you are asking engine to do extra work for no reason. Using `.forEach` is the right approach here.

Comment: It also reduces the readability of code as `.map` is expected to return something and final value is assigned to something, but you are doing none and adds a gap in understanding.

Comment: I agree, now :) Thanks