# ES6 for of with keys and generator

Tags: javascript

If i have an array:

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5] -
```

I can loop with:

```
for (let [i, x] of arr.entries()){..}
```

If i have a generator function:

```
function* g() {
   yield 1; yield 2; yield 3;
}
```

I cannot.

So the questions  is how to get index and key of  loops with for of and generator.

Is there the same syntax for both regular array and generator.

And lastly why generators hasnt method "entries" since they are both iterable.

Whats the point of iterable if they are accessed in different ways.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10179815/how-do-you-get-the-loop-counter-index-using-a-for-in-syntax-in-javascript/10179849#10179849, “for iterables in general”. `entries()` is for map-like things, which generators aren’t (you can’t do `g()[0]`).

Comment: Generators don't create the entire array. they run another iteration of the function every time a `next` is called. generators are usually infinite. That's one of the reasons an `entries` function won't work good enough for your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually generators works a bit differently than normal iterable data data structure.
just for fun if you want index and values out of some generator you can if what you are yielding does have a index. you cant yield anything you need.

```
function* gen() {
 const a = [3, 5, 6];
  for (let  [key, value] of a){
   yield [key, value];
  }
}

for (let [i, x] of gen()){
  console.log(i, x);
}
```

Comment: [Never iterate an array with `for..in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in#Array_iteration_and_for...in)

Comment: Also, the `a` is not scoped to the generator function.

Answer (score 1):

You basically want to use the [Array.prototype.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/entries) on a generator, that doesn't work in that way.

However, you can easily transform your generator in an array, and *then* use the `entries` method:

```
function* g() {
  yield 1; yield 2; yield 3;
}

for (let [i, x] of [...g()].entries()){..}
```

Comment: Once a generator is transformed to an array just for iteration (in most cases, this is not possible, as generators can be infinite), the point of generators is lost IMHO.

Comment: exactly. whats the use of using generators then :P

Comment: This is a perfect valid scenario (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators that basically has the same); and *if* we want to use methods like `entries` that's the most viable option.
Otherwise, I totally agreed that the original question is flawed, since generators have a different data structure and they should be used differently.

Comment: The point of using a generator, compare to a flat array, is multiple. You don't have to calculate everything upfront – instead of the array – but only when the generator is called: you *may* want to have a "snapshot" of the generators for the iteration instead of a "living list" (e.g. the difference between a static nodelist and live htmlcollection), etc.