# how can i have a count for every other variable?

Tags: c++

```
int i;
static int count = 0;
while (1)
{
    cout << "Enter the index number for the product you want to purchase!" << endl;
    cin >> i;
    switch (i)
    {
        case 1:
            count++;
            cout << "stationary box" << "(quantity=)" << count << endl;
            break;
         case 2:
            count++;
            cout << "Remote control car" << "(quantity=)" << count << endl;
            break;
         case 3:
             count++;
             cout << "Magnet" << "(quantity=)" << count << endl;
             break;
    }
        

        
}
```

Comment: use 3 counters?

Comment: i actually used a static count array which did the job

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get loop counter/index using for…of syntax in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10179815/get-loop-counter-index-using-for-of-syntax-in-javascript)

Comment: There's no point in using static variables here.

Answer (score 1):

- Use three count variables: `count 1`, `count2`, `count3`
- Then increment them in the switch-case statement according to the input

```
int i;
int count1 = 0, 
    count2 = 0, 
    count3 = 0;
while (1)
{
    cout << "Enter the index number for the product you want to purchase!" << endl;
    cin >> i;
    switch (i)
    {
        case 1:
            count1++;
            cout << "stationary box" << "(quantity=)" << count1 << endl;
            break;
         case 2:
            count2++;
            cout << "Remote control car" << "(quantity=)" << count2 << endl;
            break;
         case 3:
             count3++;
             cout << "Magnet" << "(quantity=)" << count3 << endl;
             break;
    }     
}
```