# TypeError: .for is not iterable / array[Symbol.iterator]().next().value is not iterable

Tags: javascript, node.js, iterator

Given this code:

```js
let arr = await fetch(...).then(r => r.json());
for(let [a, b] of arr) {
  console.log(a, b);
}
```

What could cause the cryptic/unhelpful error message `.for is not iterable` in Chromium/Node.js? On Firefox the error message is instead `Uncaught TypeError: arr[Symbol.iterator]().next().value is not iterable`.

This confused me for a few minutes so I figure until they make these error messages more friendly it'd be helpful to have an SO question/answer for it. See answer below.

Answer (score 13):

This error occurs because the array contains non-arrays - e.g. it may contain objects like this:

```js
let arr = [{a:1, b:2}, {a:3, b:4}];
```

So the `for/of` code should look like this instead:

```js
for(let {a, b} of arr) {
  console.log(a, b);
}
```

Comment: in my case, the values of the inside objects are also arrays. The result is that b is `undefined`. Do you know why is that?

Answer (score 0):

I found a very nice answer to this case [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10179815/get-loop-counter-index-using-for-of-syntax-in-javascript/10179849#10179849)

Requiring ES6 and only for arrays:

```
for (const [i, value] of myArray.entries()) {
    console.log('%d: %s', i, value);
}
```

For any kind of iterable:

```
function* enumerate(iterable) {
    let i = 0;

    for (const x of iterable) {
        yield [i, x];
        i++;
    }
}

for (const [i, obj] of enumerate(myArray)) {
    console.log(i, obj);
}
```